# Mysql build query dynamically with placeholders using Limit , How to create this in store procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, build, limit

I want to implement custom paging in my store procedure there for I used limit, It works fine when I execute query in MY SQL  as static

sample select  query

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( (TIMEDIFF(FIS.ArrivalTime,FIS.DepartTime) ))) )AS duration,FID.FlightInstanceId,FID.FlightScheduleDate FROM FlightInstanceDetails AS FID
LEFT JOIN FlightInstanceSegmentAdjuster AS  FIS ON FIS.FlightInstanceId = FID.FlightInstanceId
WHERE FID.FlightInstanceId > 6
GROUP BY FID.FlightInstanceId 
LIMIT 1, 5;
```

But now I want dynamically for pagging using perameters therefore I used as

```
SET @skip=skip; SET @numrows=numrows;
SET @ID = ID;
PREPARE STMT FROM '
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( (TIMEDIFF(FIS.ArrivalTime,FIS.DepartTime) ))) )AS duration,FID.FlightInstanceId,FID.FlightScheduleDate FROM FlightInstanceDetails AS FID
LEFT JOIN FlightInstanceSegmentAdjuster AS  FIS ON FIS.FlightInstanceId = FID.FlightInstanceId
where FID.FlightInstanceId > 6
GROUP BY FID.FlightInstanceId 
LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

still working and getting data

[image]

when I create this query as store procedure  then it is execute successfully but it didn't gives any result

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydatabase`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_Temp`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`mydatabase`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_Temp`(
    skip INT,
    numrows INT,
    ID INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE skip INT;
DECLARE numrows INT;
DECLARE ID INT;
SET @skip=skip; SET @numrows=numrows;
SET @ID = ID;
PREPARE STMT FROM '
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( (TIMEDIFF(FIS.ArrivalTime,FIS.DepartTime) ))) )AS duration,FID.FlightInstanceId,FID.FlightScheduleDate FROM FlightInstanceDetails AS FID
LEFT JOIN FlightInstanceSegmentAdjuster AS  FIS ON FIS.FlightInstanceId = FID.FlightInstanceId
where FID.FlightInstanceId > @Id
GROUP BY FID.FlightInstanceId 
LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

calling

```
CALL SP_Temp(1,5,40)
```

My question is when I calling this store procedure then it gives no result.where I am gone wrong ? I want to use Store procedure.

Answer (score 2):

`@Id` must also use a placeholder.

Try:

```
PREPARE STMT FROM '
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( (TIMEDIFF(FIS.ArrivalTime,FIS.DepartTime) ))) )AS duration,FID.FlightInstanceId,FID.FlightScheduleDate FROM FlightInstanceDetails AS FID
LEFT JOIN FlightInstanceSegmentAdjuster AS  FIS ON FIS.FlightInstanceId = FID.FlightInstanceId
where FID.FlightInstanceId > ?
GROUP BY FID.FlightInstanceId 
LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @Id, @skip, @numrows;
```

In the above query I replaced this line:

```
where FID.FlightInstanceId > @Id
```

with this one:

```
where FID.FlightInstanceId > ?
```

Comment: Thx kordirko it is working , but still I need change in query for custom pegging. because limit '@skip' ,  '@numrows' , @skip :skip only one it is not use like page

Comment: `LIMIT x, y` measn "skip x rows, then return y next rows". If the page has Z rows, you must calculate yourself how many rows must be skipped using `@skip = Z * (pageNo-1)` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Build query dynamically and Custom paging with Limit() is clear now and working.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydatabase`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_Temp`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`mydatabase`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_Temp`(
    skip INT, -- page number 
    numrows INT, -- page index 
    ID INT -- any of your where condition parameter 
)
BEGIN
DECLARE skip INT;
DECLARE numrows INT;
DECLARE ID INT;
SET @skip= (skip * numrows) - numrows  ; 
SET @numrows=numrows;
SET @ID = ID;
PREPARE STMT FROM '
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( (TIMEDIFF(FIS.ArrivalTime,FIS.DepartTime) ))) )AS duration,FID.FlightInstanceId,FID.FlightScheduleDate FROM FlightInstanceDetails AS FID
LEFT JOIN FlightInstanceSegmentAdjuster AS  FIS ON FIS.FlightInstanceId = FID.FlightInstanceId
where FID.FlightInstanceId > ?
GROUP BY FID.FlightInstanceId 
LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @Id, @skip, @numrows;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```